# How to save pages with unique names?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am using C# and sql database. In db is stored information about items - id, name, etc.

Now i have a page to show items, that i use as a template and pass Item id in the url like /Item.aspx?id=223.
I would like to create pages for every item and save them to folder like /Items/Red-Book.aspx.
Any suggestions?

Thanks, Walt

Comment: The question is vague, are you asking how to rewrite the URLs? So instead of the id parameter in the querystring, you would like to see the product name?

Comment: look this https://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net+rewrite+url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to save the pages physically. You only need one page Item.aspx which will generate the content according to the ItemiId you supply. (the same way you explained in the question)

After you have this page you need to look into how to rewrite URL.

What rewrite URL does is that it takes the url that a user requested and rewrites it to something else.

If a user request **/Items/Red-Book.aspx** the url will be rewrited to /Item.aspx?id=223 and youre ASP.NET will load **/Item.aspx?id=223** back to the client.

You can make use of the method RewritePath which you can call at Application_BeginRequest to rewrite your URL.The logic would be as follow:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var currentPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path;
    // do some logic to generate newPath
    var newPath = GetNewPath ( currentPath );
    HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(newpath);
    // after this point ASP.NET will work as the user would have requested newpath
}
```